# from a NSDictionary I only get 0 or null what should I do?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

this is my snippet

```
NSArray * alphabets = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",@"f",@"g",@"h",@"i",@"j",@"k",@"l",@"m",@"n",@"o",@"p",@"q",@"r",@"s",@"t",@"u",@"v",@"w",@"x",@"y",@"z",nil];
NSMutableDictionary * alphaToNum = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

NSInteger index =0;

for (NSString * character in alphabets) {

    index++;
    [alphaToNum setObject:character forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:index]];
}

NSLog(@"%@",[alphaToNum objectForKey:@"d"]);
```

and every time I try to get some value for my key I only get 0 .

Comment: Try just doing `NSLog(@"%@, alphaToNum);` - it'll print the entire dictionary so you can see whether it's empty or not and what keys are in it.

Comment: yeah the dictionary is filled with data : 2011-10-24 12:09:48.109 prog[21780:a0f] {
    19 = s;
    8 = h;
    16 = p;
    5 = e;
    24 = x;
    13 = m;
    2 = b;
    21 = u;
    10 = j;
    18 = r;
    7 = g;
    26 = z;
    15 = o;
    4 = d;
    23 = w;
    12 = l;
    1 = a;
    20 = t;
    9 = i;
    17 = q;
    6 = f;
    25 = y;
    14 = n;
    3 = c;
    22 = v;
    11 = k;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need...

```
NSLog(@"%@",[alphaToNum objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[alphabets indexOfObject:@"d"]]]);
```

Comment: Because the keys are numbers and strings are the values.

Answer (score 0):

Your keys are `NSNumber`s, your objects are the letters from a to z. There is no object for key @"d". There will be an object, the string @"d", for the key `[NSNumber numberWithInt:4]`. Have you got your keys and objects the wrong way around? What do you actually want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Following code will produce your desired result.

```
NSLog(@"%@",[alphaToNum objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:4]]);
```

Problem with your `NSlog` is this.

Keys are made up of NSNumbers, which are starting from `1`, not of alphabets. => since there is no key with letter '`d`', it will send you null in return.

Comment: can u tell me how to load 20 ccsprites in ccp(20,20) using nsdictionary